# how to select random index based on the current time

Tags: php, algorithm

Given an array of length N, how do I select a random index based on the current time. Basically I wanted to generate a random integer from 0 to N based on the current time. Is this even possible to do mathematically?

Comment: Why it has to be based on the time? and not just random?

Comment: because I wanted it to be selecting the same number for every 30 minutes

Comment: Would [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) % N work?

Comment: Yea that would definitely work using UNIX timestamp % N but it will change the index every second, I would want it to change every X minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seed a random number generator with a derived value from `time()`:

```
mt_srand(time() / 30 / 60); // reseed every 30 minutes

echo mt_rand(0, N);
```

Without a random number generator you can simply use modulo:

```
echo (time() / 30 / 60) % N;
```

Note that `mt_rand()` output may include N itself whereas the module version doesn't.

Comment: I think that's just a little bit more efficient then my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Think your looking for something like this:

```
<?php

    $numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    $random = date('i')/5 % count($numbers);
    echo  $random . "<br />";
    echo $numbers[$random];

?>
```

Comment: that would change every second.. I want this to change every X minute.. how do I do that into this equation?

Comment: @adit ? Did you tried it? It only change every minute! Because date('i') gives the minutes back! so only every minute the calculation change!

Comment: yea that is way too fast, I want to be able to control it.. I want it to change it every 10 minute, 15 minute, etc

Comment: @adit So you want every 5 min a random value which is every 30 min's the same?

Comment: Do, `date(i)/x` where `x` is the number of minutes you want the interval to be. So it would just capture that.

Comment: @VivekPradhan Thanks! I'm just a little confused, because it seams that OP want's every 5 min a random value which is every 30 min's the same! So it's would be a list with 6 numbers which change every 5min to the next

Comment: Ok, @Rizier123, I guess I get your point. The OP probably needs to clarify his question further.